# angularjs value on load incorrect

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

See this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/jUaXmSCyb0aEdixb5SN4?p=preview)

I want to use an object model on an `input` (for interaction with the angularui bootstrap typeahead).  It works perfectly when selecting something from the typeahead, but on load it displays `[object Object]`  How can I get the input to display a property of the model object on load?

Comment: please add ng-model="selected.name" and try.

Comment: @rajkamal you are missing the point.  I need the ng-model to be the actual object.  In my actual app, the typeahead has the objects returned from the (server side) search, and I need the id out of the selected object.  If I set the model to the name, I no longer have access to the rest of the properties of the object the user selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is currently a bug in ui-bootstrap that is fixed in master and will be out soon.  I also misunderstood the ui-bootstrap build files and was including both the templated and the non-templated versions in my app.

I monkey patched my ui-bootstrap and switched to templated only and it is now working for me.

see the google group [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular-ui/MjsKEwgkxM0/_OSFQ_K9CvcJ)

Answer (score 10):

Just in case someone else landed here just like me, having a `[object Object]` being displayed in some input(s)...

In my case, I named the `form` element with the same name of the model property, like this:

```
<form name="contact">
   <input type="text" ng-model="contact.name" />
   <input type="text" ng-model="contact.email" />
</form>
```

Either change the form `name` to a different name, or change the model name.

As Angular populates the `$scope` with a property with the same name as the `form`, it overrides the model instance!

Comment: This saved the day for me! The parent element was a <div> and I simply added the name property to it and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this also and docs don't show how to hook into bootstrap `updater` callback.

I did it by setting initial value to string. When you type in the field model will be a string. When you select from dropdown it will be object

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{id:1,name:"google"}, {id:2, name:"microsoft"}];
  $scope.selected = '';


  $scope.$watch('selected',function(newVal,oldVal){    
    if(newVal && angular.isObject($scope.selected)){
      console.log($scope.selected)
    }
  })
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aT5GATjCkqTYd4JZHs5N?p=preview)

Perhaps ther is a better way using directive's attributes but not sure what that is

Answer (score -1):

Angularjs Form showing [object Object] on load in form fields

It occurs only if your form name and ng-model name (value) are same

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would say 1. It's not true that it is *only* the name collision that causes the problem I had. 2. Someone else already gave the answer you did more than a year ago (and much more clearly).